How to compute Hessian-vector product over a subset of parameters
I'm trying to get eigenvalues and eigendensity of the Hessian matrix over a subset of (ResNets') parameters.
I was using PyHessian Package from https://github.com/amirgholami/PyHessian. Since it's impossible to print out the whole Hessian due to the parameter size, similar algorithms uses Hessian-vector product. For example, in PyHessian, the authors define:
def hessian_vector_product(gradsH, params, v):
    """
    compute the hessian vector product of Hv, where
    gradsH is the gradient at the current point,
    params is the corresponding variables,
    v is the vector.
    """
    hv = torch.autograd.grad(gradsH,
                             params,
                             grad_outputs=v,
                             only_inputs=True,
                             retain_graph=True)
    return hv

Now here is what I'm stuck... The locations of the parameters I want to examine are irregular. They could be some entries from 1 tensor and some from another, totally random. Is there any ways to achieve my goal without modifying functions like torch.autograd that are so fundamental, or writing a function from scratch? Thank you so much!
I initially try to flatten gradsH, params, and v, but in this way, torch.autograd.grad() would lose its functionality.
